# Почему "питание" и "воспитание" - не однокоренные?

Tags: этимология, морфология, однокоренные-слова

У Тихонова сказано, что у "воспитания" корень "воспит", а не "пит"? При этом, этимологически, "воспитание" и "питание" оба происходят от слова "питати" ...
Почему же корень разный?

Есть похожие пары - например, "товар" и "товарищ" - этимологически связанные, но не однокоренные. Тут мне понятно: суффикса "ищ" не существует, приходится отнести эту часть к корню.

Но с "воспитанием" иначе: "вос" - вполне себе нормальная приставка. Восхождение, восполнение, восстание ... Чем именно "воспитание" отличается от всех этих?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147432/discussion-on-question-by-dima------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.